# Unit test DB calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a class with static functions performing DB operations such as save, retrieve and delete.

My DB class:

```
public final class DbUtils {

    static {
        DB_USER = //get from secure server
        DB_PASSWORD = //get from secure server
    }


    private static Connection establishConnection() {
    }

    private static void closeConnection(Connection connection) {

    }

    public static boolean saveObject(final Object graph, final Object map) {

        Connection connection = establishConnection();
        try {
            byte[] bgraph = ConvertToByte(graph);
            byte[] bmap = ConvertToByte(map);
            statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT IGNORE INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES (?,?)");
            statement.setObject(1, graph);
            statement.setObject(2, map);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            //Close statement within try catch
        } catch(Exception e) { // also other exception
            //catch to catch all type of exception
        }
        closeConnection(connection);
        return true;
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> retrieveObject(final String key) {
        Connection connection = establishConnection();
        //read byte and convert to object
        closeConnection(connection);
        return map;
    }

    public static boolean deleteObject(final String key) {
        Connection connection = establishConnection();
        //delete all object except object with key
        closeConnection(connection);
        return (affectedRow >= 1);

    }

}
```

I wrote a unit test to test it like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DbUtils.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("DbUtils")
public class DbUtilsTest {

    @Mock
    Connection connection;

    @Mock
    ModuleDependencyGraph dependencyGraph;

    @Mock
    private Map<String , String> moduleSDF;

    @Test
    public void testSaveObject() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(DbUtils.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(connection).when(DbUtils.class, "establishConnection");
        Assert.assertTrue(DbUtils.saveObject(dependencyGraph, moduleSDF));
    }
}
```

When i try to run this unit test i get a null pointer error at the `statement = connection.prepareStatement` line which is to be expected i think since I'm not mocking the connection properly. How do I mock the connection properly? Also is the way I have written the `saveObject` test correct? I am new to unit-testing so I don't know the best-practices and how to cover all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Mock
Statement statement;

doReturn(statement).when(connection).prepareStatement(anyString());
doNothing().when(statement).setObject(any(), any());
doNothing().when(statement).executeUpdate();
```

This is using just Mockito. You can as well use PowerMockito. It should work none the less.

Comment: i should add these line after `PowerMockito.doReturn(connection)...` right? Except the `@Mock` part.

Comment: `setObject` and `executeUpdate` are giving error. Is there any import to add since the IDE isn't suggesting any? `setObject` is giving `cannot find symbol` error and `executeUpdate` is giving `no suitable method found for executeUpdate(no arguments)` error.

Comment: setObject and executeUpdate are method on `Statement` class

Comment: Resolved that error. `setObject` is not a method on `Statement` class but it is on `PreparedStatement` and `executeUpdate` requires a `string` as sql query to execute as argument. I changed the type for `statement` to `PreparedStatement` and modified the `setObject` line to `PowerMockito.doNothing().when(statement).setObject(1, any());
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(statement).setObject(2, any());` but now i get `Invalid use of argument matchers! 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded: -> at DbUtilsTest.testSaveObject(DbUtilsTest.java:52)` (line 52 is `setObject` with 1 as parameter index.

Comment: you cannot mix real values(1, 2) with Matchers(any()). change 1 and 2 in setObject to `eq(1)` and `eq(2)`